# Xpath - Using the text outside a tag

Tags: html, xpath

```
<span class="spanClass">

    NAME:

</span>

JOHN

<i class="remove"></i>
```

How do i use JOHN on my xpath? Something similar to //a/span[contains(text(),'NAME')] not sure how to do it when text is already outside of the span tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get **JOHN** with `//a/text()`. Basically it will return text that not wrapped in tags. [Example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8143a2c8016f5c43107666dda63e2f5e)

**Update 1.** In case if you want to rely on **NAME** text you can use `..` and then `text()` in addition to xpath that you have like so:

```
//a/span[contains(text(),'NAME')]/../text()
```

**Update 2.**
As I understood from your latest comment you want to get **NAME: JOHN**. That achievable with **union** (`|`) operator:

```
//a/span[contains(text(),'NAME')]/text() | //a/text()
```

Comment: How do i get to incorporate the text JOHN into my xpath that I can later change to a variable? When i'm trying to //a[contains[text(),'JOHN')] other element gets selected. I want it to use the "JOHN" where the span text "NAME:" is.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'm actually using the xpath as an object that i need to click so I wanted both the "NAME" and "JOHN" text on the same context of the xpath. I was trying like //a/span[contains(text(),'NAME')]/../contains(text(),'JOHN"). Thanks again..

Comment: @juststartingtolearn I updated my answer. Please try next time to describe better what exactly you want in your Question.